# What is the equivalent of "grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 <file> " in Solaris?

Tags: linux, grep, solaris

What is the equivalent of `grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 "$file"` in Solaris?

In Linux it works fine. but in Solaris, i got "grep: illegal option -- e
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . ." error.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's your second `-e` for? That's not correct on Linux either; you should only have a `-e` before a pattern, not a filename.

Comment: Also, which version of Solaris? [POSIX `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html) requires `-e` to be supported immediately before a pattern.

Comment: Ahh. I've edited your question to be more clear.

Comment: Quite simple: The equivalent is `ggrep .....`. Both on Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 GNU grep is installed by default. You may need to update your path though. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
# GNU grep only
grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 file
```

...you can use:

```
# POSIX-compliant
grep -e 'pattern1
pattern2' file
```

Comment: its "grep -e $pid -e <any string> "....sorry for missing out string part..this string can have regular expressions/(-) also..

Comment: perfect..the question is now very much clear..In Linux "grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 file" means pattern1 or pattern2 and "grep -e 'pattern1|pattern2' file" means pattern1 and pattern2 ....how it will be for Solaris?..i do not have solaris system so can not check..

Comment: It should be `grep 'pattern1\|pattern2'` (Note the backslash, no `-e`) or `grep -e "pattern1\npattern2"` (Note the newline) . I may be wrong but that's how I read the POSIX spec.

Comment: @sahilmittal, no, `pattern1|pattern2` does not mean "pattern1 **and** pattern2" on Linux; it's "or" even there, though hek2mgl is correct that it doesn't work as-is (needs a preceding backslash) without `-E`.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I agree with you that the original code was wrong, though I'm not sure that `\n` can be used to replace a literal newline.

Comment: So, the answer is " grep 'pattern1\|pattern2' "?? @hek2mgl,could you please check on Solaris if it works.(eg1: ps -ef|grep 'pattern1\|pattern2') (eg2: ps -ef|  grep -e 'pattern1|pattern2')(eg3: ps -ef |grep -e 'pattern1\npattern2') t. please share the output so it's clear to me and everyone who gonna check this post.. thanks a lot..

Comment: @sahilmittal, the second form of the answer here, with the literal newline, is guaranteed by black-letter POSIX, so there's no need to check for OS-dependent extensions. That said, if we want to know which version of the POSIX spec you need compliance with, **or which version of Solaris `grep` to test against**, we'd have to know the version of Solaris you're targeting. Just "it works against some random version of Solaris" isn't likely to be helpful.

Comment: @sahilmittal, ...Solaris 11, for instance, has **finally** come into the modern world and installed ksh93 as `/bin/sh`. Doesn't matter for `grep` behavior, but if you were asking about whether some other random shell feature "works on Solaris", the answers would be hugely different between Solaris 10 and Solaris 11. Different versions differ.

Comment: @sahilmittal, ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html -- that's the standard that every UNIX OS vendor builds their tools to comply with, Sun included. Search for "newline" in the text, and read the relevant bits.